# Prob with binary files using sockets

Tags: c, sockets, binaryfiles, binary-data

This is not the total code.

This is working fine for normal files like text files, but not working for tar.gz and binary files transfer please help me.

And how to send the chunks of memory using sockets.

server.c

```
void main()
{
int sockfd, new_fd;  // listen on sock_fd, new connection on new_fd
struct sockaddr_in my_addr; // my address information
struct sockaddr_in their_addr; // connector's address information
socklen_t sin_size;
struct sigaction sa;
int yes=1;
char buf[16384];
char remotefile[MAXDATASIZE];
if ((sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == -1)
{
    perror("socket");
    exit(1);
}

if (setsockopt(sockfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &yes, sizeof(int)) == -1) 
{
    perror("setsockopt");
    exit(1);
}

my_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;        // host byte order
my_addr.sin_port = htons(MYPORT);    // short, network byte order
my_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY; // automatically fill with my IP
memset(my_addr.sin_zero, '\0', sizeof my_addr.sin_zero);

printf("call binding\n");
if (bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&my_addr, sizeof my_addr) == -1) 
{
    perror("bind");
    exit(1);
}

if (listen(sockfd, BACKLOG) == -1) 
{
    perror("listen");
    exit(1);
}

sa.sa_handler = sigchld_handler; // reap all dead processes
sigemptyset(&sa.sa_mask);
sa.sa_flags = SA_RESTART;
if (sigaction(SIGCHLD, &sa, NULL) == -1) 
{
    perror("sigaction");
    exit(1);
}

while(1)
{  // main accept() loop
    sin_size = sizeof their_addr;
    if ((new_fd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&their_addr, &sin_size)) == -1) 
    {
        perror("accept");
        exit(1);
        continue;
    }
    printf("server: got connection from %s\n",inet_ntoa(their_addr.sin_addr));
    if (!fork()) 
    { // this is the child process
if ((byt=recv(new_fd, remotefile, MAXDATASIZE-1, 0)) == -1) 
            {
                perror("server recv");
                exit(1);
            }
        int serverfile_fd;
        size_t result;
        printf("\nremotefile in val1 is %s\n",remotefile);

        if((serverfile_fd = open(remotefile,O_RDONLY)) < 0)
        {
            printf("error at remotefile\n");
            exit(1);
        }

        else
         {  
            read(serverfile_fd, &buf[0], sizeof(buf));
         }
        //printf("file is\n%s", buf);
        /* 3. sending  buf in val 0*/
        if (send(new_fd, buf, 16384, 0) == -1)
            perror("send");
        close(new_fd);
        exit(0);
    }
```

client.c

```
int remote_to_local(const  char *remotehost,const  char *remotefile,const  char *localfile)
{

int sockfd, numbytes,i = 0,j = 0;  
char buf[16384];
struct hostent *he;
struct sockaddr_in s_addr; // connector's address information 
printf("\n");
printf("Remotehost is %s\n", remotehost);
if ((he=gethostbyname(remotehost)) == NULL) 
{  // get the host info 
    perror("gethostbyname");
    exit(1);
}

if ((sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == -1) 
{
    perror("socket");
    exit(1);
}

s_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;    // host byte order 
s_addr.sin_port = htons(PORT);  // short, network byte order 
s_addr.sin_addr = *((struct in_addr *)he->h_addr);
//inet_aton(he->h_addr, &s_addr.sin_addr);
memset(s_addr.sin_zero, '\0', sizeof s_addr.sin_zero);

if (connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&s_addr, sizeof s_addr) == -1) 
{
    perror("connect");
    exit(1);
}

//send(sockfd, remotefile, MAXDATASIZE-1, 0);
val[0] = 1;
printf("Val 0 is %d\n", val[0]);
printf("Val 1 is %d\n", val[1]);
        /*1 sending val in r to l*/
if (send(sockfd, val, MAXDATASIZE-1, 0) == -1)
            perror("send");

printf("remotefile is %s\n",remotefile);

/* 2 sending remotefile in r to l*/
if (send(sockfd, remotefile, MAXDATASIZE-1, 0) == -1)
            perror("send");
/* 3. recieve buf in r to l */  
if ((numbytes=recv(sockfd, buf, 16384, 0)) == -1) 
{
    perror("recv");
    exit(1);
}

buf[numbytes] = '\0';

//printf("Received: \n%s",buf);


int clientfile_fd;
printf("Local file is %s\n",localfile);
if((clientfile_fd = open(localfile,O_CREAT|O_WRONLY,0777)) < 0)
    {
       printf("error at remotefile\n");
        exit(1);
    }
   else
   {    
        //read(clientfile_fd, &buf[0], sizeof(buf));
         int  result = strlen(buf); 
         //printf("Result size is %d\n",result);
         open(localfile,O_TRUNC);
         write(clientfile_fd, &buf[0], result);
   }

close(sockfd);


return 0;
  }
```

Comment: printf("\nremotefile in val1 is %s\n",remotefile);' assumes a null-terminated string.  value returned by recv() not fully handled.   That's the first two 'usual suspects' dealt with, now to find the strlen() calls...

Comment: 'int  result = strlen(buf);' calling strlen() in binary data that may contain nuts.

Comment: 'buf[numbytes] = '\0'; pointless with binary data that may contain shellfish.

Comment: Sending `MAXDATASIZE-1` bytes regardless of the actual number of bytes in the file is a really poor idea.  It's wasteful for files that are smaller, and it truncates files that are larger.

Comment: what is nullterminated string ?

Comment: how is it related to recv()

I am using  
printf("\nremotefile in val1 is %s\n",remotefile);' to print how does it effect the recv()

Comment: What is a nullterminated string ? If you don't know that you should not be trying to program sockets yet. First try a book on programming for beginners. You are most likely copy pasting pieces of code that you don't understand at all.

Comment: I know what is null terminating string but I cant understand how does it related to recv()

Comment: ^^ You understand that binary data, in general, may contain nulls, yes?  OK, so can you understand why using library calls that require null-terminated char arrays will be unreliable when applied to such data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go through ALL your code and fix/change ALL the places where you:

- don't correctly handle the results returned by system calls like
  recv().  If a positive value is returned, that value is the ONLY safe
  way of finding out how much data has been read into the buffer.
- Get rid of all the strlen(), printf("%s...) etc. that are either
  useless, (the binary data may contain nulls and so the action will
  complete early), or dangerous, (binary data contains no nulls at all
  and so the calls are UB).

Comment: Also, `recv()` is not guaranteed to receive all the incoming data in one call, even if there is enough space in the buffer.  You need some sort of application-level protocol to indicate how much data to read, and you need to keep reading until you read that much.  (Such a protocol could be as simple as the client closing the connection when all bytes have been sent.  I guess it actually does that, but the server does not necessarily read to the end of the stream.)

Comment: Also also, similar applies to sending.

Comment: Can u please give me any idea about how to do it

Answer (score 0):

Following logic for receiving a file is already a lot better than what you have. But there are a lot more problems with your code than just this :

```
 FILE *received_file;
 received_file = fopen(FILENAME, "w");
 ...
 //copy logic, copies data received from the socket into the file as is.
 while (((len = recv(client_socket, buffer, BUFSIZ, 0)) > 0))
    {
            fwrite(buffer, sizeof(char), len, received_file);
    }
    fclose(received_file);
   close(client_socket);
```

The receive is continuously called until your receive 0 or a negative number, if you receive 0 that means you need to close the socket because the transfer is finished and the peer has closed its end of the connection too.
The file handle should be created right after accept.

Bottom line is that your code needs a total revision because it is too lengthy for what it is supposed to do, and it is based on totally wrong assumptions. Read first about network programming before attempting anything like this. Socket programming is an advanced topic, without proper understanding you will fail.